# How to access Repeater FooterTemplate TextBox?

Tags: asp.net

- What I am trying to do is to access the value from the TextBox1 to display back on the screen.
- I tried to access it from the Page_Load() and the OnItemDataBound and they both failed.
- It seem like the code is able to access the control but it return nothing back.

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

  ```
      Literal Literal1 = (Literal)Repeater1.Controls[Repeater1.Controls.Count - 1].FindControl("Literal1");
      Response.Write(Literal1.Text);
      //this techique is not working for the line below
      TextBox TextBox1 = (TextBox)Repeater1.Controls[Repeater1.Controls.Count - 1].FindControl("TextBox1");
      Response.Write(TextBox1.Text);

  }
  public void myRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
  {
      //this techique is not working
      if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer)
      {
          TextBox TextBox1 = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("TextBox1");
          Response.Write(TextBox1.Text);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: <form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="myRepeater_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
<div>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Text='<%#Eval("RepeaterLabel")%>' />&nbsp;</div>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
<div>Enter you text in the below to test.</div>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="" size="50px" />
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Literal1" Text="Literal IS OKAY"></asp:Literal>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Submit" />
</form>

Comment: something wrong with the stackoverflow editor. Can't paste the code into the original post.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "they both failed" but if the Text property of the Textbox is empty i might be because you are rebinding your repeater on each post back. Try wrapping your repeater .DataBind() with a !IsPostBack condition.

Answer (score 0):

I have to use "Literal" as an alternate solution by passing the html Textbox  problem. I do not like this solution but i guess i have to use it.